# Display Multiple Row from Multiple Colomns sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table PRODUCTS :

```
> ITEM         t1   t2   t3  t5   t6  t7  t8
> ------------------------------------------- 
>SHIRT         XS   S    M   L  
>DRESS         XXS  XS   S   M    L   XL 
>TSHIRT        S    M    L
```

And I want to display this :

```
>ITEM         SIZES
>-------------------------------------------
>SHIRT        XS   
>SHIRT        S    
>SHIRT        M 
>SHIRT        L
>DRESS        XXS  
>DRESS        XS   
>DRESS        S   
>DRESS        M  
>DRESS        L   
>.
>.
>.
```

Can you please help me to fix this diplay?
TIA,

Comment: Your database design is really poor! That's why you are having difficulties displaying the result you want. Normally, you are supposed to have a many to many relationship between a `Product` and `Size`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to use `apply` for sql-server

```
with cte as
(
  select a.*, rank() over (order by a.Sizes)[rn] from PRODUCTS p
  cross apply(
    values (p.ITEM, p.t1),
           (p.ITEM, p.t2),
           (p.ITEM, p.t3),
           (p.ITEM, p.t5),
           (p.ITEM, p.t6),
           (p.ITEM, p.t7),
           (p.ITEM, p.t8)
     ) as a(Item, Sizes)
)

select Item, Sizes from cte
order by case when rn = 1 then Item else '0' end, case when rn = 1 then '0' else null end, Item
```

Answer (score 0):

simpliest solution coming to mind at first is

```
select ITEM, t1 as SIZES from PRODUCTS 
union all
select ITEM, t2 as SIZES from PRODUCTS 
union all
select ITEM, t3 as SIZES from PRODUCTS 
union all
select ITEM, t4 as SIZES from PRODUCTS 
union all
select ITEM, t5 as SIZES from PRODUCTS 
union all
select ITEM, t6 as SIZES from PRODUCTS 
union all
select ITEM, t7 as SIZES from PRODUCTS 
union all
select ITEM, t8 as SIZES from PRODUCTS
```